# Laravel Eloquent inserted record twice times

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models: `Customers` and `Attendance` (The relationship is One - Many). I tried to insert a record into the `attendances` table when a customer access to a URL to check in.

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->attendances()->create(['checked_in_at' => now()]);
```

However I don't know why above code inserted 2 times instead 1 times, and sometime it inserted correctly 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to log/store the check-out time as well.
Then put an If in check-in function to check if the user is not checked out yet than do not check-in again.
If you don’t put a check; double clicks, page refreshes all will trigger multiple check-ins
Another option is to link the check-in with login event, you just have to make an event listener for login event.

Answer (score 1):

The user may try to hit the URL twice (for whatever reason, poor internet connection or something else)

You can run another query to make sure that the user will not have a duplicated rows or two attendances in a short period of time.

You can run a query like this

```
$last_attendance = $customer->attendances()->orderBy('checked_in_at', 'DESC')->first();

if(Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($last_attendance->checked_in_at) > 5){
    $customer->attendances()->create(['checked_in_at' => now()]);
}
```

This will make sure that it takes at least 5 min to insert a new record, or you can change the value as you want.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that way, but I just want to know why it inserted 2 times. I tested by myself, and I just hit enter 1 time :(. Thank you.

Comment: best solution in such situation is debugging, and as you are already logging time, you can check what is the delta between the two check-ins, it may help in find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a submit button that allows the user to double click calling it twice.